# Iphone load XIB/m/h Problem

Tags: iphone, sdk, viewdidload

why does this not work:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
Login *neu =[[Login alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:neu animated:NO];
}
```

but this works

```
-(IBAction)dologin:(id)sender{
Login *neu =[[Login alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:neu animated:NO];
}
```

I wanted to load a specified class directly when one is loaded,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will work if you move `[self presentModalViewController:neu animated:NO];` to `viewDidAppear:`

That way the modal view controller will pop up as soon as the view appears.

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad:` isn't where you want to put up a modal view. It might be called after a low memory warning unloads your view controller, and then when the user navigates back to it, it will unexpectedly try to show a modal view. If you want to present something when the app launches, do so in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` in your app delegate, or set up a NSNotfication observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidFinishLaunching:) name:UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification object:nil];
```

and call `presentModalViewController:` there.